# Inno Setup Compiler adding trailing spaces to executable details (ex.: FileVersion, LegalCopyright, ...)

Tags: inno-setup, trailing

What could be the possible cause of trailing spaces in *Version Info* of the resulting executable file? How to remove them ? (Removing the spaces with *Resource Hacker* yields the executable corrupted)

This is the excerpt from *Version Info*, viewed with *Resource Hacker*.

```
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "000004b0"
    {
        VALUE "Comments", "This installation was built with Inno Setup."
        VALUE "CompanyName", "name                                                        "
        VALUE "FileDescription", "installer                                                  "
        VALUE "FileVersion", "3.0.5.0             "
        VALUE "LegalCopyright", "copyright                                                                                           "
        VALUE "OriginalFileName", "file.exe                                        "
        VALUE "ProductName", "some product                                               "
        VALUE "ProductVersion", "3.0.5.0                                           "
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that it's just how it works.

Inno Setup-generated exe is based on a pre-built binary. It includes "Version Info" placeholder with a fixed space for each field. On compile time that placeholder is filled with real data, keeping remaining spaces.

See the ["Version Info" placeholder](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/SetupLdr.version.rc) in Inno Setup repository.